# bash getopts - difference between ${OPTARG} and $OPTARG

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

When passing arguments to a Bash-script like:

```
1   while getopts u:d:p:f: option 
2   do 
3   case "${option}" in 
4   u) USER=${OPTARG};; 
5   d) DATE=${OPTARG};; 
6   p) PRODUCT=${OPTARG};; 
7   f) FORMAT=$OPTARG;; 
8   esac 
9   done
```

from: http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Pass-Arguments-To-A-Bash-Script.htm

What is the difference between `${OPTARG};;` line 4-5-6 and `$OPTARG;;` line 7?

Comment: Nothing. They are identical. You need the `${var}` form when you need to expand a variable *inside* a word. `echo foo${var}bar` as opposed to `echo foo$varbar` (which will be seen as the `$foobar` variable).

Comment: thanks Etan! and is  `echo foo${var}bar` equivalent to `echo "foo"$var"bar"` ?

Comment: @RafaSashi  `echo "foo"$var"bar"` won't work it's not properly quoted, `echo foo${var}bar` is equivalent to `echo "foo$var"bar`

Comment: `echo "foo"$var"bar"` will work (as `$var`) and is syntactically validly quoted. It is also exactly backwards from a quoting perspective as it quotes the literal strings and not the variable expansion.